# PostgreSql upsert: which explicit locking method?

Tags: locking, postgresql-9.2, upsert

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-postgresql/8702291#8702291), I want to use the following method to perform upserts in a PostGreSql table:

```
UPDATE table SET field='C', field2='Z' WHERE id=3;
INSERT INTO table (id, field, field2)
   SELECT 3, 'C', 'Z'
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id=3);
```

I understand I have to perform it in a transaction and that I should use an explicit locking method. I have been reading the postgresql documentation, but I am still hesitating between three types of locks (the difference between each is not crystal clear for me):

```
ROW EXCLUSIVE
SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE
EXCLUSIVE
```

I would like to avoid having to retry the transaction. I am not expecting much concurrency on the rows, though this could happen from time to time. There might be simultaneous attempts at deleting and upserting the same row in rare cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need *self-exclusive* lock type that also *excludes all DML commands*.

The correct lock type for this operation is `EXCLUSIVE`. It conflicts with all other locks, including its self, *except* `ACCESS SHARE`.

`ACCESS SHARE` is taken by `SELECT`. All other commands require higher locking levels. So your upsert transaction will then block everything except `SELECT`, which is what you want.

See [the docs on explicit locking](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html).

So:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
...
```

(The historical, and awful, naming of some table level locks using the word `ROW` does not ease understanding of PostgreSQL's lock types).

BTW, your application should check the rowcount returned from the `UPDATE`. If it's non-zero, it can skip the `INSERT`.

Comment: Mega thanks, I had a feeling I should use exclusive, but I wondered whether it was overkill...